# How to run IOS Unit tests from the command line on xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

I've been trying to figure out how to run our Unit Tests from the command line, so that we can automate them.
I'm using XCode 4.5.2, and building an IOS application.

First I tried using this:

> ```
> xcodebuild  -target "Unit Tests" -configuration "Debug (test syncserver)" -sdk iphonesimulator6.0 clean build TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES
> ```

That would run the compile, but the test didn't run.
So, after reading other solutions around here, I installed ios-sim and setup my target to run this script afterward:
(Note that I had to replace occurences of "TEST_HOST" with "CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH" as TEST_HOST doesn't seem to exist in my builds.)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$RUN_UNIT_TEST_WITH_IOS_SIM" = "YES" ]; then
    test_bundle_path="$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.$WRAPPER_EXTENSION"
    echo ios-sim launch "$(dirname "$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH")" --setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection --setenv XCInjectBundle="$test_bundle_path" --setenv XCInjectBundleInto="$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH" --args -SenTest All "$test_bundle_path"
    ios-sim launch "$(dirname "$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH")" --setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection --setenv XCInjectBundle="$test_bundle_path" --setenv XCInjectBundleInto="$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH" --args -SenTest All "$test_bundle_path"
    echo "Finished running tests with ios-sim"
else
    "${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests"
fi
```

Now, when I run the same xcodebuild command as before, I get this:

> /bin/sh -c
>   "\"/Users/johnlussmyer/tu/ondeck/OnDeck/build/OnDeck.build/Debug (test
>   syncserver)-iphonesimulator/Unit
>   Tests.build/Script-4CECE52812D5043F0063EC6A.sh\"" ios-sim launch
>   /Users/johnlussmyer/tu/ondeck/OnDeck/build/Debug (test
>   syncserver)-iphonesimulator --setenv
>   DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection
>   --setenv XCInjectBundle=/Users/johnlussmyer/tu/ondeck/OnDeck/build/Debug (test
>   syncserver)-iphonesimulator/UnitTests.app --setenv
>   XCInjectBundleInto=/Users/johnlussmyer/tu/ondeck/OnDeck/build/Debug
>   (test syncserver)-iphonesimulator/UnitTests.app --args -SenTest All
>   /Users/johnlussmyer/tu/ondeck/OnDeck/build/Debug (test
>   syncserver)-iphonesimulator/UnitTests.app [DEBUG] Session could not be
>   started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 "Unknown
>   error." UserInfo=0x7fcf04b03190 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown
>   error., DTiPhoneSimulatorUnderlyingErrorCodeKey=-1} Finished running
>   tests with ios-sim

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Answer (score 3):

From the log, it seems you have several wrong settings. The correct syntax is:

```
ios-sim launch YourApp.app 
--setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/../../Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEBundleInjection.framework/IDEBundleInjection 
--setenv XCInjectBundle=YourTest.octest 
--setenv XCInjectBundleInto=YourApp.app/YourApp 
--args -SenTest All YourTest.octest
```

You could see that

1. the app path is incorrect after launch command
2. XCInjectBundle should be your octest instead of app
3. XCInjectBundleInto should be your app binary path instead of app folder
4. The last argument should also be your octest

If you can't see TEST_HOST in your environment variables, you may want to go through them to find some propers ones to make your bash script correct.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old question.. but I fall here some similar question.

My two cents for OSX/ iOS (tested under iOS13 / Catalina / Xcode 11). (hope it can help someone..)

```
func underXCTest()->Bool{
    let environment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
    if let _ = environment["XCInjectBundleInto"]{
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Under testing return false.